# Get All Friends/Connections Profile pic details from Facebook and LinkedIn in IOS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, linked-list, linkedin-api

I'm working on application related to contact management. In this i'm accessing all device contacts in my application.

App: Contact Management
Platform: Application running on IOS9.

I just want, if any of user don't have contact image associated with it in device then I would like to retrieve it from Facebook contacts by requesting contact email or number to get Contact profile pic as response.
I just need profile pic of Facebook contacts to show in my application contact, As i have searched and reviewed so many API and complete Graph API for it, but unfortunately i have not found any solution from it.
I have checked all Friend-LIst API, but not works Or not got proper response from any of them.

I'm only getting the friends name and details, those have authorised my app. but at least I need all of my Friends list with profile pic details, of user's friend who logged in.
Page on facebook.com
My Application neither us game app. nor we have any canvas page for it.
Can you please suggest me what i needed Is possible some-how? Or it's not possible at all. OR any Paid plan for it?

I would really thankful, if I got perfect solution for it.

I also needed same thing for LinkedIn Connections. But not found Pricing details for their Partners program.

Comment: For Facebook: You can only get friends that are users of your app as well. Access to all friends, including non-users of your app, is not possible any more.

Comment: thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Access to Connections data via LinkedIn is only available to LinkedIn developer partners.  It is not managed via pricing, but rather via use-case.  To apply for access to the developer program, go to: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply